# Getting an unauthorized-401 error every first time I call, but it works once I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

**Each time I call the user API, I get an unauthorised error, but it works after I have refreshed the page**

**1. This is my fetch user method**

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

import AuthContext from "../../store/auth-context";
import { getUserInfo } from "../../lib/api";



const Products = () => {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(authCtx.contextValue.token);
  const userData = decodedToken.data.userData;


  const fetchUserInfo = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    getUserInfo(userData.id).then((response) => {
      let groupId = response.data[0].work_group;
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserInfo();
  }, []);
```

**2. This is my user api call**

```js
export async function getUserInfo(userId) {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const response = await fetch(`${CODE_CORP_API}/users/${userId}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || "Could not create account.");
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: What ray said and also that code is simply not enough. For example, your useEffect calls fetchUserInfo, yet there is no fetchUserInfo function in sight. It also impossible to help with functions, when you don't know what half of the variables and their values are and where do they come from. You talk about a refresh-related issue, but only show us mere two functions and none of the behaviour.

Comment: @Swiffy I have updated my question, could you please check now and let me know

Comment: Nice, this is a lot more workable now, but I'd still add some more info, such as what the network tab of devtools says about the request and since you are using localStorage, it would be nice to see what's in there regarding this issue. Anyway, since this works after a refresh, that should give you a hint that this could have something to do with, e.g. first load setting the token into localstorage, but doing it only after getUserInfo has already failed, since it tries to get the token. Maybe after a refresh that token is there.

Comment: Note that localstorage is not the only possible culprit. Think of everything your app could write or "persist" somewhere, like cookies, auth info, default states, ... as those are your usual suspects when something only works after a second load.